# Support for Unity 4 in facebook sdk 7.x is required

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

facebook sdk for unity  v7.1 says Unity 4 is no longer supported. 
Unity 5 is required

It is painful for upgrading unity4 to 5 due to lagacy projects is still using unity4.x
I believe there are a lot of developers has same requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your platform, v7.1.0 may work, only way to know is to test. It is not supported on Android due to the need for AAR's which requires Unity 5. But you can experiment to your hearts content on other platforms, only limitation is that it is unlikely Facebook will support bugs that only manifest in Unity 4.

Comment: thanks , the another way may be using native sdk speaks to Unity.